# Registration form doesn't save addition field in database with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Maybe is silly question but I have a problem with my registration form. I have added one addition field to be saved in database `users` table but this addition textarea value isn't saved.

All other inputs such as username, password are saved correctly. This is the addition textarea

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Bio</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">                                
          <textarea class="form-control" name="bio" id="bio" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
</div>
```

And the AuthController.php store function

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //dd($data);
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'bio' => $data['bio'],
    ]);
}
```

When I do `dd($data)` I see that the $data contain the Bio value.

Column bio is with type `text` in database so, is not truncated or something.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Have you added bio to your fillable array in the user model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment) issue.

In your `User` model, you will have an array defined as `public $fillable = [...];`

You will need to add `'bio'` to the array to allow it to work from the `User::create([]);` function

Comment: Oh, I didn't really knew this. I'm kind of new in Laravel. Why I can't add them straight away but need to add them in fillable?

Comment: Yeah. It restricts what can be entered.

Answer (score 0):

I your model add the bio in protected fillable.
Like this one.

```
protected $fillable = ['name','email','password','bio'];
```